# Why Blowing Up other player's Personal Vehicle consider as Bad Sport?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I once tried to stick a Sticky Bomb on other player's personal vehicle when the player was away for shopping for guns in Ammu-Nation. When he got back on his ride, BOOM!

But a message pops up on the left top of the screen said,

> Blowing Up other player's Personal Vehicle is considered as "Bad Sport"

Why? Will I get any penalty?

Comment: You blew up his car, dude.

Comment: Dude, where's his car?

Comment: up in the air, with his burning body; before the BOOM, parked outside Ammu-Nation.

Comment: Why?  Because Rockstar decided so, that's why!  Will you get any penalty?  Yes.  Do it enough and you'll end up playing on a server where only other bad sports can play (initially for 2 days), and believe me it's an unpleasant place to be if you do actually want to play the game properly, and your chances of increasing your time in there are very high.

Comment: what do you mean by "only other bad sports can play" ? do you mean no missions at all?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - He means you will only play with players flagged as being "bad sports".

Comment: Another thing I've found about the bad sport lobby (and really frustrates me) is that if someone blows up your car then *you* pay the insurance cost for the replacement, not them.  Basically, leave your cars at home and don't use them because there's usually at least 1 tank roaming the streets and, unlike London where the streets are paved with gold, in the bad sport lobby the streets are paved with sticky bombs!

Comment: This isn't a dupe, it's a totally different question with a completely different answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put yourself in the other player's shoes (that's what nice people do -- this applies to real-life too).

Now imagine that you've just got a car (say it's one you stole from an NPC) and spent loads of money pimping it out. It's shiny! You're very happy with it :-)

Then one day a 'bad sport' comes along and pops a sticky bomb on your car and blows it to high-heaven.

You're upset. But then you realise that you didn't get insurance. D'oh! And that makes you even more upset :-(

You take this pent-up rage and go off to find other players' cars to blow up. You don't care if it's the same guy who just blew up your car, or just some other chump who caught you on a bad day. To satisfy your rage you blow up 10 players' cars.

Those 10 people then get angry and go around blowing up even more cars. This spirals out of control until the world of GTA becomes a ghost-town, with everyone gunning each other down at every available opportunity. At this point you've got Mors Mutual Insurance on speed dial, and it's getting really tedious.

I guess that's why R* had the forethought to banish all those d*cks to their own wasteland, to blow up each other's cars. I have been in a few lobbies where my car gets blown up every 5 mins, but thankfully they are few and far between, mostly because of the 'bad sport' system.

So kids, the moral of the story is: don't be a d*ck. (and make sure you have insurance, just in case you do come across any!)

Comment: So, killing people with automatic weapons is fine, but blowing up cars isn't?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Using weapons to have a bit of fun is what GTA is all about! Going out of your way to repeatedly waste the (hard-earned?) money/possessions of others is a problem that most MMO games face. R* have chosen the bad-sport system to try and overcome this problem. I'm glad it's there. It's not perfect, but then you can't please everyone.

Comment: Oh, I'm not complaining, just poking a bit of fun at the discrepancy.

Comment: I thought blowing up cars & popping people's heads are very common in game. R* can't expect players to behave like good guys, following traffic lights, etc.